# ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’

Tags: r, rstudio

I am getting the following error when i try to install plyr package, I have tried some of the solutions suggested in other threads but they dont seem to be working. I have recently upgraded the version of R and R studio on the server

```
> install.packages("plyr")
Installing package into ‘/home/arsvis5/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/2.15’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘Rcpp’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rcpp_0.11.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2004313 bytes (1.9 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 1.9 Mb

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/plyr_1.8.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 393233 bytes (384 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 384 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h: In member function ‘void Rcpp::Date::update_tm()’:
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h:108: warning: converting to ‘time_t’ from ‘double’
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h: In function ‘Rcpp::Date Rcpp::operator+(const Rcpp::Date&, int)’:
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h:139: warning: converting to ‘time_t’ from ‘double’
Date.cpp: In function ‘double Rcpp::mktime00(tm&)’:
Date.cpp:57: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
Date.cpp:60: warning: converting to ‘int’ from ‘double’
Date.cpp: In function ‘tm* Rcpp::timesub(const time_t*, long int, const Rcpp::state*, tm*)’:
Date.cpp:1196: warning: converting to ‘long int’ from ‘double’
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Module.cpp -o Module.o
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h: In member function ‘void Rcpp::Date::update_tm()’:
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h:108: warning: converting to ‘time_t’ from ‘double’
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h: In function ‘Rcpp::Date Rcpp::operator+(const Rcpp::Date&, int)’:
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h:139: warning: converting to ‘time_t’ from ‘double’
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Rcpp_init.cpp -o Rcpp_init.o
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h: In member function ‘void Rcpp::Date::update_tm()’:
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h:108: warning: converting to ‘time_t’ from ‘double’
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h: In function ‘Rcpp::Date Rcpp::operator+(const Rcpp::Date&, int)’:
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h:139: warning: converting to ‘time_t’ from ‘double’
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c api.cpp -o api.o
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h: In member function ‘void Rcpp::Date::update_tm()’:
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h:108: warning: converting to ‘time_t’ from ‘double’
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h: In function ‘Rcpp::Date Rcpp::operator+(const Rcpp::Date&, int)’:
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h:139: warning: converting to ‘time_t’ from ‘double’
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c attributes.cpp -o attributes.o
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h: In member function ‘void Rcpp::Date::update_tm()’:
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h:108: warning: converting to ‘time_t’ from ‘double’
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h: In function ‘Rcpp::Date Rcpp::operator+(const Rcpp::Date&, int)’:
../inst/include/Rcpp/Date.h:139: warning: converting to ‘time_t’ from ‘double’
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:87953: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
{standard input}:89432: Error: undefined symbol `.LLSDATT10675' in operation
{standard input}:89435: Error: undefined symbol `.LLSDACSE10675' in operation
g++: Internal error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <URL:http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
make: *** [attributes.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/home/arsvis5/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/2.15/Rcpp’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available for package ‘plyr’
* removing ‘/home/arsvis5/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/2.15/plyr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘plyr’ had non-zero exit status


> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] codetools_0.2-9 RMySQL_0.9-3    DBI_0.3.0      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.0
```

Comment: Try to install just Rcpp. What are the other suggestions you have tried (make it clear or provide links). Post your `sessionInfo()` or at least include your OS version, R/Rstudio version

Comment: I tried just installing Rcpp, got this error  {standard input}:78314: Error: expected comma after name `_ZN4Rcpp10attributes26SourceFileAttributesParser14parseArgumentsERKS' in .size directive
g++: Internal error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report.


Added seesion info above in the question description

Answer (score 5):

The issue was resolved after upgrading RAM on my server, the package was not installing because there was not enough memory available on the server.

Comment: Yeah the same here.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by installing `r-base-dev` package on Ubuntu, by running the command below:

`sudo apt install r-base-dev`